# CSS transition causes divs to resize during transition

Tags: css, html, transition

I have a side menu that slides out to a certain width. The slider contains divs with text. 
When the side menu is sliding out or back in (during transition) - the text attempts to resize to fit the minimising space causing all the words to briefly be in a vertical column.

Is it possible to have the text and divs fixed and the transition reveals more and more of the data in it's final formatting (i.e. how it will be displayed at the end of the transition) versus the data attempting to accommodate the ever increasing/decreasing space?

Here is the transition code:

```
.slider {
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 0;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing full code in jsFiddle? Hard to understand.

Comment: Perhaps overflow: hidden;

but it is hard to say without a full example ...

Comment: @Tsasken perhaps combined with `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: White-space: nowrap did it! Brilliant thank you for the speedy response

Comment: did you give a width to inner content ? else it shrinks within the space left avalaible :)